# Make a rain like CSS Transitions

Tags: html, css

I want a tag to  fall down infinitely. I tried to do this with CSS transition, but can't get it to work.

I want the `.fall` to constantly rain down. How can I get this to work?

Sorry for making a wag question but may be the fiddle will clear up what I want to accomplish.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/077mtLgj/)

HTML

```
<div class='rain'>
    <p class='fallSec'>
        < $ " " 1 0 1 0 0 0 $ 1 0 2 ( { $ 1 0=) 0 1 0 0 0 1 }
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rainSec {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rainSec .fall {
    width: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 10s infinite;
    animation: fadeInDown 10s infinite;
}
.rain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rain .fallSec {
    color: blue;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 36px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 8s infinite;
    animation: fadeInDown 8s infinite;
    transition-delay: 8s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the JSFiddle not the way you want it to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed your makup and the animation settings, now the symbols fall down constantly without blank space between them :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cLdrcgft/)**

```css
html,body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
.wrap{position:relative;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}
.rainSec, .rain {
    font-size:2em;
    color:blue;
    width:1em;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0.5em;
    bottom:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.rain{
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 8s infinite;
    animation: fadeInDown 8s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

}
.rainSec {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 8s 2s infinite;
    animation: fadeInDown 8s 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateY(200%); }
    50.1%{ -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(200%); }
}
@-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translateY(200%); }
    50.1%{ -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(200%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <p class='rain'>< $ " " 1 0 1 0 0 0 $ 1 0 2 ( { $ 1 0 = ) 0 1 0 0 0 1 }</p>
    <p class='rainSec'>< $ " " 1 0 1 0 0 0 $ 1 0 2 ( { $ 1 0 = ) 0 1 0 0 0 1 }</p>
</div>
```